# React change handler not able to pick name property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I am not able to get `event.target.name` even though I am assigning value to name property

```
handleSectionDObservation = event => {
  if (event.target.value === "Observation" && event.target.name !== "Observation") {

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      CalcNoOfObs2: this.state.CalcNoOfObs2 + 1,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });

    console.log([event.target.name])
  } else if(event.target.name === "Observation") {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      CalcNoOfObs2: this.state.CalcNoOfObs2 > 0 ? this.state.CalcNoOfObs2 - 1 : 0,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log([event.target.name])
  };
}
```

Comment: Where this event is being called? OnClick event?

Comment: have you set name from where this event is triggering??

Comment: Can you provide your return too?

Comment: this is an onChange event

Comment: `else if(event.target.name === "Observation")` this condition is not working in OnChange

Comment: You are logging out event.target.name - but you are setting a name property on state. Also setState() is asychronous so if you want to see state after you have set it you will need to write it like this: setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }, () => console.log(state));

Comment: `console.log` working this way as well but it's not logging my intended `value` which I am assigning to `name`

Comment: @SnehalRamteke you aren't setting event.target.name to be event.target.value  - you are setting state[name] = value, ie setting something in state itself, nothing to do with the event.

Comment: Then How I can set `value` to `name` property and then compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setState` function will not update your values synchronously, your state will not be changed right away. The second parameter of it allows you to give a callback function triggering when the state has been mutated.

You also do not need to update all the state values at once, the one that you give are the only one that are going to be affected. And if you need to use the old state values, you should use the callback version of `setState` :

```
this.setState(oldState => ({
  CalcNoOfObs2: oldState.CalcNoOfObs2 > 0 ? oldState.CalcNoOfObs2 - 1 : 0,
  [event.target.name]: event.target.value
}), () => { console.log(this.state[event.target.name]) });
```

The whole function can also be reduced to the following to avoid repetitions :

```
handleSectionDObservation = event => {

  if(event.target.name !== "Observation" && event.target.value !== "Observation") return;

  const CalcNoOfObs2 = event.target.name === "Observation" ? 
    this.state.CalcNoOfObs2 > 0 ? this.state.CalcNoOfObs2 - 1 : 0 :
    this.state.CalcNoOfObs2 + 1;

  this.setState(oldState => ({
    CalcNoOfObs2,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  }), () => { console.log(this.state[event.target.name]) });

  console.log([event.target.name]);
}
```